# Custom window component in Blazor with minimize and maximize functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created custom component for Dialog with options to minimize and maximize dialog. I created one instance of dialog on click button and then minimized and again clicked on button to create new instance and now I have list of these two window references. I want to change State in options of one reference by Id to maximize it again.If I change state for now, The last opened instance state gets changed.

```
var windowInstance = new RenderFragment(builder =>
        {
            builder.OpenComponent<Blazor7WindowInstance>(0);
            builder.AddAttribute(1, "Options", options);
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "Title", title);
            builder.AddAttribute(3, "Content", windowContent);
            builder.AddAttribute(4, "Id", windowInstanceId);
          
            builder.CloseComponent();
        });
```